# Blazor onclick event is not triggered

Tags: c#, onclick, blazor

I try to implement a simple onclick event handler like [this sample](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/counter), but it is not working in my solution. The event is only triggered at the run of the web page for unknown reasons.

The HTML page with Blazor component is well shown, but when I click on the button, nothing is happening.

I'm on [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019) and .NET Core 3.0, with an [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) project.

#### *Counter.razor* file

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount();">Click me</button>

@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => currentCount++);
    }
}
```

#### File *Index.cshtml*

```
@using WebApplication2.Views.Components

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Server, new { }))
```

#### File *startup.cs*

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change 
        // this for production scenarios; see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The button in the browser:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,WebApplication2.Views.Components.Counter+<IncrementCount>d__2];">Click me</button>
```

The error in the browser:

[Bug in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krqU7.png)

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console (F12 in the browser).

Comment: your code is different in places - suggest you recheck eg. you're missin the `@page` directive on the counter page...

Comment: @PascalR. No error in browser.

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: ok I check the doc, the @page directive nothing change

Comment: Sould be `<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount();">Click me</button>`.

Comment: Also check your Program.cs and make sure that you are not affected by this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14373

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have the exact same problem?

Comment: @leen3o: `@onclick="IncrementCount"`. Just create a new project and see the Counter page.

Comment: Did you ever get this working, @micsp24 ?

Comment: @sanepete: The OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*

Answer (score 66):

This answer is only for .net 8, where static rendering is the default. .net 8 introduced the notion of Render Modes, and it is now required either at the page level, or globally. The default is static rendering which means that the component is rendered exactly as it is written with no interactivity being wired up by the Blazor engine. This is nice if you have pure static html, and don't need the overhead of the interactivity. On the other hand, it can catch you by suprise if have used earlier version and your click event is just not getting processed and there is no obvious reason for it.

To wire up interactivity, you have two options.

**Per component solution**
Check for this directive at the top of the file:

```html
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

If it's missing, then you will not get events being fired.
On the client side (wasm) it will be this:

```html
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
```

**Global solution**
Update `Routes` element in `App.razor` file:

```html
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

The Global solution allows you to use interactive elements in the `MainLayout.razor` which is not supported in the per component solution. This can be useful if you are doing something like wiring up a "dark" mode and need a class to be applied at the top level of your html so it gets applied to everything.

Edit: Even though you have added `AddInteractiveServerComponents()` this does NOT mean that you have set the default to be InteractiveServer. It only means that you have the option to add InteractiveServer as a global or component option. So you still must add the global or component option as above.

Comment: This was the solution for me but the syntax was changed in the .net 8 release to `@rendermode InteractiveServer`

Comment: I have updated the answer to the new syntax.

Comment: Thanks to @Vita for the suggested edits. This question and answer have becoming surprisingly popular with the upcoming release of .net 8

Comment: I dont know why, but this code works! Thanks!

Comment: I was about to start a new question for this very issue. @GregGum, Thank you for your efforts. This saved me.

Comment: This answer is correct, but what initially confused me is the presence of `AddInteractiveServerComponents()` in my service registration. But then when I re-read the docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#enable-support-for-interactive-render-modes it does say this:

"Individual components are still required to declare their render mode"

Comment: @DylanMunyard, Good point, and I have added this clarification.

Answer (score 42):

This is the most popular question related to the problem: *Blazor onclick events don't get triggered*. Adding to the answers that resolved the OP's problem and were unable to resolve mine, I would like to add that:

`<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` need to be placed *after* the component that declares the events, not in the `<head />` tag. Possibly at the very bottom of the `body` tag of `_Host.cshtml` or your MVC View that needs `Blazor` components. If you don't do it, Blazor syntax will still work, the project *will* compile and most things *will* behave as expected, but the events won't be triggered.

I just spent hours trying to figure that out.

Also if `@onclick` is not recognised as Blazor code in *.razor* files at all (this can happen especially in *Component Libraries*), make sure to add `_Imports.razor` at the very top of the project with the following content:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

If for some reason some of the namespaces can't be found, they can be added as [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) packages.

Comment: Pay particular attention to _Imports.razor at the very top of the project. I had this file in the Pages directory and everything would render but no interactivity worked.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was moving using to the _imports and somehow onclick stopped working on some pages. I was missing some of the using statements in your list.

Comment: I did not see any difference when moving the location of the blazor.server.js <script> tag. What DID work for me is adding the _Imports.razor as described above. Once I added that, syntax highlighting worked on '@onclick', and more importantly, the event fired.

Comment: Adding _Imports.razor in Components folder also fixed the problem for me, thank you.

Answer (score 28):

I think your call to the onclick event is wrong. They changed the way you reference functions from

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

to

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

The `@` is now in front of the `@onclick` and *not* in front of the function name.

Comment: I tried already this. I think that is not correct because in the browser the button seems like: <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount();">Click me</button>

Comment: the code behind will not compile if you are using the release version of  .net 3.0  if you  try the code as you have posted it will fail in blazor fiddle  it yo change it to the new structure it compiles fine and works

Comment: Also if you follow the link to the blazor fiddle example you linked  they have changed the structure to this between preview 7 to 3.0 release. And the only thing you say is not working is to onclick.

Comment: This answer should work (additionally the (); part is not needed)

Comment: The `();` part will make it not work or even not compile.

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same issue, but I found the solution in *[onclick method is not working in Blazor server-side Razor component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368714/onclick-method-not-working-in-blazor-server-side-razor-component/58444907#58444907)*.

You need to add a `_Imports.razor` file into your Components folder with the following *using* statements.

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web namespace worked for me! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This, I had _Import.razor.cs in my Pages folder, I had to add one to my Components Folder aswell

Comment: Adding _Imports.razor in Components folder also fixed the problem for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `<button @onclick=IncrementCount`

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me ended up being quite a bit different than the other answers here. I was using Cloudflare [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to help serve my Blazor Server application.

In the end, I needed to turn off 'HTML Minification' in Cloudflare to get my onclick events working again.

Turn this setting 'off' in Cloudflare in the 'Speed' settings section:

[image]

For additional options for getting around the issue, please reference this blog post:

[ASP.NET Core Blazor with SignalR breaks when used with Cloudflare's HTML minification by Tobias Zimmergren](https://zimmergren.net/solved-asp-net-core-blazor-web-sites-does-not-work-with-cloudflare-html-minification/)

I also ran into this same [HTML Minification issue using Scully with Angular and Cloudflare](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/131#issuecomment-847199379).

Additional helpful blog post: *[Blazor Server events not triggering when hosted behind Cloudflare](https://gordonbeeming.com/blog/blazor-server-events-not-triggering-when-hosted-behind-cloudflare)*

Answer (score 3):

I've just had a very strange case of this problem: this code wasn't triggered.

```
<div ... @onclick=@(_ => OnClick.InvokeAsync(EventArgs.Empty))></div>
```

The problem's root is still unclear, but the solution (or rather a workaround) was to replace lambda with a method name.

```
<div ... @onclick=OnClickHandler></div>

@code {
  private void OnClickHandler()
  {
    OnClick.InvokeAsync(EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to figure out most of the solutions for **Blazor inside the ASP.NET MVC application**. Some are incomplete, so I’ve tried to prepare complex instructions which work for me. If you are working on **Blazor inside an ASP.NET MVC application, you have to do the following stuff.**

Go to the _Layout.cshtml or index.html and in the bottom script section, add

```html
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

In the same file, *_Layout.cshtml* or *index.html*, in the *head* tag section right after the *[title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title)* or *meta* tags, add:

```html
<base href="/" />
```

Or alternatively

```html
<base href="~/"/>
```

Create the *_Imports.razor* file inside your Blazor components directory and add to it following using statements:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

Alternatively, you can add these statements directly at the beginning of your component file.

Use onclick as follow:

If you want to pass parameters:

```
@onclick="(()=>YourEvent(yourParams))"
```

Or simply if you just want to call:

```
@onclick="YourEvent"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was migrating a prior project (Razor Pages) to Blazor. I was missing the `head` option.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I added *StaticFileOptions* in file *Startup.cs* like this (I used this code in my ASP.NET Core project):

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
   OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
   {
       const int duration = 60 * 60 * 24;
       ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = $"public,max-age={duration}";
   }
});
```

Then I returned to

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();
```

and it started to work.

Comment: This worked for me aswell! Was getting a "Failed to load resource _framework/blazor.server.js" in the browser console but once i reverted to just app.UseStaticFiles() everything worked.

Comment: I had the same problem. Adding "if (path.EndsWith("blazor.server.js")) return;" to the "OnPrepareResponse" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `RenderMode.Static` to `RenderMode.Server` will probably solve your problem since you use server-side Blazor. But as JohnB suggested, you should read the documentation. Learn about the difference between server-side Blazor and client-side Blazor at *[ASP.NET Core Blazor hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0)*.

Comment: I changed several pieces of code (post is updated) and the render mode but the event is not triggered when I click on the button. I have now an error in browser.

Comment: There isn't anyone here by the name "JohnB". What does it refer to? A comment to the question? [jazb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196812/blazor-onclick-event-not-triggered#comment102773462_58196812)? Something else?

Comment: Yes, jazb's comment, he probably renamed his account in the last 4 years. Not that it would matter...

Answer (score 1):

I had all my Blazor components in a separate "class library" project.

Including *@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web* in the component solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try add @ at onclick like this

`<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>`

Thanks
Joon

Answer (score 1):

Maybe learn the difference between a return value of an executed method and a method-type aka as delegate e.g. `Action`

```
IncrementCount(); // Is a method that returns void (or string, or a Task, if you want)
var returnValue = MyMethod2();


// These declare and initialize delegate variables
var action = IncrementCount;
var action2 = MyMethod;
Func<int> myFunc = MyMethod2;
MyDelegate myDel = MyMethod3;
```

You want to provide a delegate to the `@onclick` **directive**, ... not use the old syntax, nor a return value (although it’s possible)

```
<button @onclick=@Hahaha()>Click me</button>
<button @onclick=@Foo>Click me</button>
<button onclick="console.log('Hahaha Foo')">Click me</button>
<button onclick=@Baar()>Click me</button>
@code {
Action Hahaha(){
return Foo;
}
void Foo() {
i = 5;
}
}
string Baar()
{
    return "console.log('Boofar')";
}
```

The code `onclick="@IncrementCount();"`
is simply dead wrong in at least three ways.

- why would there be `"` if you dont wanna provide a string
- why use the `;` if there is no `block` at all -> learn about the @ `directive`
- not using @onclick
- using a implicit string conversion of a Task object returned from a method, which is absolutely not what is desired here

The framework does exactly what you tell it todo:
casting the Task into a string with the implicit ToString(), append a ';' and pass that as the JavaScript code for the html attribute `onlick` which gets exactly rendered as that. Note that this even only works for non-void methods, because void methods would not even return anything and thusly cannot used as an `expression` for a string, what is what is inferred here!

Answer (score 1):

Much like [DreamEvil 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196812/blazor-onclick-event-is-not-triggered/59860920#59860920), I was having this problem after I added `StaticFileOptions` to my `app.UseStaticFiles()` method in *Program.cs*.

I stumbled across this known Blazor issue which explains the problem:
*[Passing options to UseStaticFiles breaks Blazor Server's static file service #19578](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19578)*

There are a couple of solutions, but my favorite is by configuring `StaticFileOptions` in the Services collection before calling `app.UseStaticFiles()` (without any parameters).

```
builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx=>
    {
        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WebAssembly .net8.
For this to work on server-side pages, was necessary to include
**.AddInteractiveServerComponents()** and **.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()**
on the *Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerComponents()
.AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();
```

and

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
.AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
.AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(SiteCasamento.Client._Imports).Assembly);
```

and than include rendermode in the pages

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you are embedding this in an MVC application. You don't have the script tag to it for *blazor.server.js* in the *index.cshtml*. In it you add

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"/>
```

at the bottom of the *index.cshtml* page. This is what wires up [SignalR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR) to the server, which is needed for server side.

See [Scott Hanselman doing exactly what you are trying to do](https://youtu.be/R23v4lgHYQI?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oW8nviYduHq7bmKode-p8Wy&t=636).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck all day with this problem and then discovered that was working just fine in Chrome. Therefore, I added http://localhost to my list of Intranet websites in the Windows 10 Control Panel / Internet Settings / Security page. This only needs to be done for developers running the app from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```html
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick="() => lock_invoice(r)"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> &nbsp; Lock</button>
```

And code:

```
@code {
    void lock_invoice(System.Data.DataRow row)
    {
        string id = row["id"].ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue. I just hide the unwanted buttons instead of adding and removing them.

```html
<MudItem sm="4" Style="padding-top:30px">
    <MudButton style="@ScheduleAddButton" Color="Color.Warning" Variant="Variant.Outlined" OnClick="() => SaveSchedule()">Add Schedule</MudButton>
    <MudButton style="@ScheduleRemoveButton" Color="Color.Warning" Variant="Variant.Outlined" OnClick="() => DeleteSchedule()">Delete Schedule</MudButton>
</MudItem>
```

Added code

```
if (Schedule.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    ScheduleAddButton = "display:block";
    ScheduleRemoveButton = "display:none";
}
else
{
    ScheduleAddButton = "display:none";
    ScheduleRemoveButton = "display:block";
}

StateHasChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issues by adding **@rendermode InteractiveServer**
in razor page.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The problem was running the app in [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer).

OnClick worked fine when I ran the app in [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).