# onclick method is not working in Blazor server-side Razor component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I am building a sample Razor component, and I can not get my button *onclick* method to fire. When I click the button, nothing happens at all. I have even placed a breakpoint in the method to see if it catches which it doesn't. The component does render, but as I said, the LoginUser method doesn't appear run at all when clicking the button.

Razor component page:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <Login FieldsetAttr="fieldsetAttr" UsernameAttr="usernameAttr" PasswordAttr="passwordInput"
           ButtonAttr="buttonAttr" ButtonText="Sign In" SignInManager="SignInManager"
           InvalidAttr="invalidAttr" />

</div>

@code {
    Dictionary<string, object> fieldsetAttr =
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"class", "form-group" }
        };

    Dictionary<string, object> usernameAttr =
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"class", "form-control" },
            {"type", "text" },
            {"placeholder", "Enter your user name here." }
        };

    Dictionary<string, object> passwordInput =
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"class", "form-control" },
            {"type", "password" }
        };

    Dictionary<string, object> buttonAttr =
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"class", "" },
            {"type", "button" }
        };

    Dictionary<string, object> invalidAttr =
        new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"class", "invalid-feedback" }
        };

}
```

Razor component:

```
<div @attributes="FormParentAttr">
    <form @attributes="LoginFormAttr">
        <fieldset @attributes="FieldsetAttr">
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <label for="usernameId">Username</label><br />
            <input @attributes="UsernameAttr" id="usernameId" @bind="UserName" /><br />
            <label for="upasswordId">Password</label><br />
            <input @attributes="PasswordAttr" id="passwordId" @bind="Password" /><br />
            <button @attributes="ButtonAttr" @onclick="LoginUser">@ButtonText</button>
            @if(errorMessage != null && errorMessage.Length > 0)
            {
                <div @attributes="InvalidAttr">
                    @errorMessage
                </div>
            }
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> FormParentAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> LoginFormAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> FieldsetAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> UsernameAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> PasswordAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string,object> ButtonAttr { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, object> InvalidAttr { get; set; }

    private string UserName { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }

    private string errorMessage { get; set; }

    private async Task LoginUser(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser(UserName);

        var loginResult = await SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, Password, true);

        if(loginResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
            errorMessage = "";
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Username or password is incorrect.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console? (F12 in the browser)

Comment: I have the same issue. The debugger does not break and there is no message in the debugger, even when setting the debug level to 0.

Comment: Check that you don't have `RenderMode.Static` in your `_Host.cshtml` file.

Comment: And I expect you have the latest version .Net Core 3.0 installed.

Comment: @PascalR. The app is 3.0, render mode is RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, and I am not seeing any errors in the browser. I am totally stumped on this. I've tried simplifying my onclick method a few different ways by making it a regular void non-async method, and it still didn't work.  I'm sure it must be something obvious that I am overlooking, but I simply can't figure it out.

Comment: It appears that a simple css attribute was causing the problem or preventing the method from executing. Really weird, not sure exactly why. I will be deleting the post shortly in light of the issue.  I did come across another issue now which I've posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387683/signin-for-blazor-server-side-app-not-working . The method now executes, but hangs once it hits the SignInAsync method.

Comment: @user1206480 I've the same probleme in an application where i try to add the Blazor Server Side stuff. I've already removed alle css attributes but no success. Any hint what you've done to solve it?

Comment: @maltmann I removed a bootstrap class on a div tag, and then the method fired. I have no idea why this was.  Doesn't make much since to me at all. I was just satisfied to get on the right track, and would try to figure it out later.

Comment: I opened another question for my problem and got the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436408/blazor-features-missing-in-existing-project/58444800#58444800

Answer (score 23):

This happened to me in an ASP.NET Core project where I was trying to add Blazor components following [this blog's guidance](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/). After comparing my project with the template Blazor project, I discovered that it was the missing `_Imports.razor` file that was causing *blazor.server.js* to not subscribe to the click event. I added that file to my project just as it is in the template project:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

Button clicks were then working as expected.

Comment: Yes! This has been killing me for a day. This solved the same problem I was having, and should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you

#### 1. Configure Blazor in the *Startup.cs* file:

In `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`
you call `services.AddServerSideBlazor();` (...for server-side Blazor)

and in `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`
you register the endpoint, such as ('*endpoint.MapBlazorHub()*' is what you need to add here):

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        });
```

#### 2. You have

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

in the Razor component where you're using Blazor.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, but I resolved it by changing `ServerPrerendered` to `Server`".

In your `_Host.cshtml`, change this

```html
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

to

```html
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Comment: I'm doing Blazor SSR .NET 7. Changing ServerPrerendered to Server caused my Blazor SSR app to stop working - never even showed the first/home page.

Answer (score 0):

Please also be aware that Internet Explorer also can result in similar behaviour.

I guess it is blocking JavaScript code...

This took me longer to realise than perhaps it should have.

Answer (score 0):

After following [this tutorial](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/), I was getting a 404 error stating my *_framework/blazor.server.js* file could not be found. The solution came down to adding "~/" before the *_framework/blazor.server.js*.

Comment: Does it really have a leading underscore? Is `_` literal?