# Blazor Features missing in existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I've started playing around with the new "Blazor Server App" project template in VS 2019 and everything works as expected.
Now I've tried to use some Blazor stuff in an existing .NET Core 3 ASP.NET MVC app.
I've added ".MapBlazorHub(); & .AddServerSideBlazor();" to the startup class and

`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

to the _layout file.
The new razor component gets rendered as expected and the "OnInitialized()" method in the @code block is fired. But when I try to use a button click event nothing happens - not in the VS console - not in the browser console.
After some hours of research I've found out that the syntax highlighting is different in the 2 projects:

Microsoft Blazor Server App template:

[image]

Existing project:

[image]

Also I found that the "Add - Razor Page..." context menu is only visibible in the MS template. 
But I can't find any differences in the csproject or the sln file.

I'm really stuck on this. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andreas has said, you need to add a new `_Imports.razor` file in your folder( `Views` folder or your custom folder where you restore your razor components.

_Imports.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

Structure:

[image]

> Also I found that the "Add - Razor Page..." context menu is only visibible in the MS template. But I can't find any differences in the csproject or the sln file.

The MS template uses `Pages` folder and you could see `Add- Razor Page` option.

If you are using Razor Pages project there will be `Add- Razor Page`, since you are using MVC, the option does not exist.

If you use the latest vs 2019 and asp.net core 3.0,  you could create a razor component  by clicking `Add - New Item - Razor Component` directly

Comment: Adding the _Imports.razor to the folder with the components did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In the Blazor-Template-Project you should see a _Imports.razor file containing multiple `@using` directives.

Try adding the following directive to the `Views\_ViewImports.cshtml` file in your MVC app.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

Without the using directive the razor engine doesn't know the `@onclick` should be interpreted as C# code and therefor does not wire up the event handler as expceted. That's also why VisualStudio does not highlight it as C# syntax.

If this helps, you should probably also add the other blazor relevant `@using` directives to the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Don't know about the missing 'Add - Razor Page...', sry.