# Call a function on button click in Blazor/Razor - ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, buttonclick, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I just started learning ASP.NET Core and I was following the YouTube tutorial from Microsoft (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA-3FA2kbpA&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oW8nviYduHq7bmKode-p8Wy&index=11) and when I tried to call the function on button click, it does not work.

The code is as follows:

**Button in HTML**

```
<button @onclick="(e => SelectProduct(product.Id))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</button>
```

**@Code Element - Function**

```
void SelectProduct(string productId)
{
    selectedProductId = productId;
    selectedProduct = ProductService.GetProducts().First(x => x.Id == productId);
}
```

Kindly help me debug this. The function does not get called when the button is clicked. 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was following the same tutorial. I tried an option that was given by a user and the pop-up works but it only shows the same image always. Anyone?

Comment: Please go through this section. I hope that this will help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1#build-components

Comment: Hi @KesavanSubramaniam thank you very much for your comment. However, for some reason, `@onclick` does not work for me. I have installed the dotnet version 3.1.101

Answer (score 1):

> However, for some reason, @onclick does not work for me.

It seems that you are integrating blazor into MVC / Razor Pages project.Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436408/blazor-features-missing-in-existing-project/58444800#58444800) I have answered before,
you need to add a new `_Imports.razor` file in your `Components` folder if you put your razor components there.

_Imports.razor:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me and should be the selected answer.