# ASP.Net Core and EFCore Conversion Errors with CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, crud

I have been trying to get a start on ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core and recently created a web project for it. I am receiving 3 errors in this file, 2 being the same specific error.

The errors are marked with a comment above them.

Error #1:

> Cannot convert method group 'DeleteTransaction' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Error #2:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'EFDataAccessLibrary.Models.DiscInfo'

Code:

```
@page "/DeleteEmployee/{CurrentID}"
@using EFDataAccessLibrary.Models;
@inject DiscService ObjDiscService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h2>Delete Transaction</h2>
<hr />
<h3>Are you sure?</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Employee ID:</label>
            <label>@objDisc.Id</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <label>@objDisc.Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description:</label>
            <label>@objDisc.Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <label>@objDisc.Amount</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
                                                  // Error 1
            <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@DeleteTransaction">Delete</button>
                                                  // Error 1
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
        public string CurrentID { get; set; }
        DiscInfo objDisc = new DiscInfo();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {                                                                       // Error 2
        objDisc = await Task.Run(() => ObjDiscService.DeleteTransactionDisc((objDisc));
    }

    protected void DeleteTransaction()
    {
        ObjDiscService.DeleteTransactionDisc(objDisc);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("disc");
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("disc");
    }

}
```

I have published the project to GitHub if anyone would like to take a look at it as a whole, or if you believe there is an issue in another file causing this.

https://github.com/Ocheezyy/MoneyManagementCore

Comment: Is this helpful? [Call a function on button click in Blazor/Razor - ASP.NET Core 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053760/call-a-function-on-button-click-in-blazor-razor-asp-net-core-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1**

I refer [Build components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1#build-components) and it has `<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>`. So no need to use `@` prefix for `DeleteTransaction` or `Cancel`.

**Error 2**

Your `DeleteTransactionDisc` has parameter with type `DccuInfo` and you are passing object 
of `DiscInfo`. Here is your method. `public string DeleteTransactionDisc(DccuInfo objDisc)`.

Update your method parameter type to `DiscInfo` and it will not show any error.

```
public string DeleteTransactionDisc(DiscInfo objDisc)
```

---

Moreover I see in your `DccuService.cs`. In constructor it is like below but you should have `_db = db;`

```
private readonly AppDbContext _db;
public DccuService(AppDbContext db)
{
    db = _db;
}
```

**Correct code**

```
private readonly AppDbContext _db;
public DccuService(AppDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```