# Blazor in MVC: Component gets rendered, but @onclick not working. Problem with connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use Blazor in a .net core 3 MVC project. I used a few tutorials to do this, like https://fizzylogic.nl/2019/08/18/integrating-blazor-in-an-existing-asp-net-core-application/ and https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/ .

What is working: The initialization of the Blazor component is working. The OnInitializedAsync() function gets triggered and the component gets rendered fine.

This is the call from the MVC View:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyProject.Components.Locations>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

What isn't working: using @onclick in the Blazor component. This is some sample code:

```
<span @onclick="AddLocation"></span>

@code {
    private void AddLocation(){

    }
}
```

The reason it probably doesn't work is that I get errors in the initialization of the connection. The component gets rendered not from the base path, but from the url of the specific view, and I think that messes with the connection. I receive these errors in the console of Chrome:

- [2019-12-02T09:26:08.117Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44375/Locations/_blazor'.
  _blazor/negotiate:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
  blazor.server.js:1
- [2019-12-02T09:26:08.155Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error
  e.log @ blazor.server.js:1
  blazor.server.js:1
- [2019-12-02T09:26:08.156Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error
  e.log @ blazor.server.js:1
  blazor.server.js:15
- [2019-12-02T09:26:08.156Z] Error: Error
  e.log @ blazor.server.js:15
  blazor.server.js:1 
  -Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.

The main fault is probably the '*Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44375/Locations/_blazor'*'. Requesting _blazor from the base path works. Does anyone know how to set the basepath in such a situation?

*(Yes, Blazor in a normal Razor page environment is probably easier, but I want to try Blazor in MVC.)*

## **edit 1**

`<base href="/" />` in the header seems to have fixed the errors in the console. I hoped it would fix the onclick issue, but not yet... I think the component gets somehow treated like a normal razor component, and not as a blazor component. If I look at the generated html, I can find this: `<span @onclick="AddLocation" ></span>`, and I think that is wrong (with a normal razor/blazor project, the @onclick dissapears from the html). Anyone knows the solution for this? Tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444907/1794246 , but that didn't do much.

## **edit 2**

Having a _imports.razor file in the root of the MVC project did obviously nothing. Adding these using statements to the Blazor component actually fixed the problem with the onclick (also Intellisense recognized things in the component a bit better):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
```

Comment: set the base href of your page according to your needs `<head> <base href="/" />`

Comment: @aguafrommars Thanks, that fixed the errors in the console! Didn't fix the onclick error, so something else is still wrong. See my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to the problem was changing two things:

- To fix the errors in the console I had to put `<base href="/" />` in the header of _Layout.cshtml
- To fix the actual @onclick issue I had to put these using statements in the Blazor component:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
```

After that the @onclick was working and intellisense recognized stuff a bit better in the Blazor component.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I used <base href="~/" /> for the header of my _Layout.cshtml, as written in a blank Blazor app _Host.cshtml file.

Comment: Adding a `_imports.razor` file to the root fixed the problem for me. In that file add the using `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;`. If you have your component in a specific folder, add the namespace to that folder as well. In example `@using MyAppOrModule.Components;` If you have a razor class library, this `_imports.razor` needs to be added to that class library as well.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path

### App base path

The *app base path* is the app's root URL path. Consider the following ASP.NET Core app and Blazor sub-app:

- The ASP.NET Core app is named `MyApp`:

  - The app physically resides at *d:/MyApp*.
  - Requests are received at `https://www.contoso.com/{MYAPP RESOURCE}`.
- A Blazor app named `CoolApp` is a sub-app of `MyApp`:

  - The sub-app physically resides at *d:/MyApp/CoolApp*.
  - Requests are received at `https://www.contoso.com/CoolApp/{COOLAPP RESOURCE}`.

Without specifying additional configuration for `CoolApp`, the sub-app in this scenario has no knowledge of where it resides on the server. For example, the app can't construct correct relative URLs to its resources without knowing that it resides at the relative URL path `/CoolApp/`.

To provide configuration for the Blazor app's base path of `https://www.contoso.com/CoolApp/`, the `<base>` tag's `href` attribute is set to the relative root path in the *Pages/_Host.cshtml* file (Blazor Server) or *wwwroot/index.html* file (Blazor WebAssembly):

```html
<base href="/CoolApp/">
```

Blazor Server apps additionally set the server-side base path by calling  in the app's request pipeline of `Startup.Configure`:

```cs
app.UsePathBase("/CoolApp");
```

By providing the relative URL path, a component that isn't in the root directory can construct URLs relative to the app's root path. Components at different levels of the directory structure can build links to other resources at locations throughout the app. The app base path is also used to intercept selected hyperlinks where the `href` target of the link is within the app base path URI space. The Blazor router handles the internal navigation.

In many hosting scenarios, the relative URL path to the app is the root of the app. In these cases, the app's relative URL base path is a forward slash (`<base href="/" />`), which is the default configuration for a Blazor app. In other hosting scenarios, such as GitHub Pages and IIS sub-apps, the app base path must be set to the server's relative URL path of the app.

To set the app's base path, update the `<base>` tag within the `<head>` tag elements of the *Pages/_Host.cshtml* file (Blazor Server) or *wwwroot/index.html* file (Blazor WebAssembly). Set the `href` attribute value to `/{RELATIVE URL PATH}/` (the trailing slash is required), where `{RELATIVE URL PATH}` is the app's full relative URL path.

For an Blazor WebAssembly app with a non-root relative URL path (for example, `<base href="/CoolApp/">`), the app fails to find its resources *when run locally*. To overcome this problem during local development and testing, you can supply a *path base* argument that matches the `href` value of the `<base>` tag at runtime. Don't include a trailing slash. To pass the path base argument when running the app locally, execute the `dotnet run` command from the app's directory with the `--pathbase` option:

```
dotnet run --pathbase=/{RELATIVE URL PATH (no trailing slash)}
```

For a Blazor WebAssembly app with a relative URL path of `/CoolApp/` (`<base href="/CoolApp/">`), the command is:

```
dotnet run --pathbase=/CoolApp
```

The Blazor WebAssembly app responds locally at `http://localhost:port/CoolApp`.

Comment: `<base href="/" />` in the header of the _layout.cshtml file seems to have fixed the errors in the console. The problem with the @onclick not :-( . See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was passing a specific model as parameter to component, the model has been created with DI and had no parameterless constructor. Once such default constructor was added everything started to work fine.