# UseBlazorFrameworkFiles Extension not available

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET Core MVC project with the use of Blazor wasm.

See:

[How to enable/use/configure WebAssembly Blazor in existing .NET MVC Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997246/how-to-enable-use-configure-webassembly-blazor-in-existing-net-mvc-project)

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.componentswebassemblyapplicationbuilderextensions.useblazorframeworkfiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0

But it seems that the service UseBlazorFrameworkFiles is not available.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

My setup in VS2019 is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Please help?

regards
Stefan

Comment: You're trying to add a Net6.0 framework assembly to a NetCore 3.1 framework project.  Won't work.  Why netcoreapp3,1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` version from **6.0.1** to **3.2.1** like below:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```