# How use ASP.NET Core MVC view and Blazor in at the same time?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm going to start a big project on asp.net core. And I need SPA for just admin panel.

My choice for SPA part is using Blazor web Assembly. and because the first load takes a long time I cant use Blazor for whole client part. I'm going to use ASP.NET Core MVC for other parts.

I don't know how to combine them. Any idea will be appreciated.

PS: for some reasons I don't want to grow separated solutions. I need all in one.

I need web assembly not server. I already checked adding server side Blazor to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC project.

Thanks a lot

**edited**: imagine I make 2 project in same solution. Is there any way to move from a view in mvc project to my blazor project by routing? like this : defining a link with this

href="myWebSite.come/admin/?username=john&password=123456">Enter Admin Panel

in mvc view and by clicking on this link open my blazor project. i mean is it possible to navigate between projects by routing and also use a same domain for both project?

Comment: Impossible.  You can't build a Blazor Web Assemby SPA and a DotNetCore  razor site in the same project.  You need several separate projects in the same solution.

Comment: Yes. Agree with @MrC aka Shaun Curtis said. You need learn how to add a Blazor WebAssembly project to an existing ASP.NET Core application. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790857/11398810

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers. you are really helping me. but imagine I make 2 project in same solution. Is there any way to move from a view in  mvc project to my blazor project by routing? like this : defining a link with this href=>"https://www.myWebSite.come/admin/username/password"  in mvc view and by clicking on this link open my blazor project. i mean is it possible to navigate between projects by routing and also use a same domain for both project?

Answer (score 2):

Step to Integrate Blazor and MVC in Single Project.

1. Create asp.net core MVC project from Visual Studio Project Template.
2. Go to program.cs and Add the following at builder section;

> builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

then add the following in the app section

```
app.MapBlazorHub(configureOptions: options =>
{
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
});
app.MapFallbackToController("Blazor", "Home");
```

3. Go to your HomeController; and add the following.

   ```
   public IActionResult Blazor() => View("_Host");
   ```
4. Create _Host.cshtml in the Home View Folder and the following code;

> ```
> @{
>     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
> }
> <app><component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" /></app>
> ```

5. Create App.razor file in the root of your MVC application such as ;
   Add the following code to the file;

> ```
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization 
> <CascadingAuthenticationState>
>     <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
>         <Found Context="routeData">
>             <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData">
>                      <NotAuthorized>
>                     <p>Sorry, you're not authorized to reach this page.</p>
>                     <p>You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
>                 </NotAuthorized>
>                 </AuthorizeRouteView>
>         </Found>
>         <NotFound>
>             <h1>Page not found</h1>
>             <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
>         </NotFound>
> ```

6. Create a Components folder and start Adding the blazor component to the folder. You should create import.razor file in the components folder and add the following code;

> ```
> @using System.Net.Http
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
> @using Microsoft.JSInterop    
> @using System.Text.Json        
> @using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
> @using System.IO;
> @using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
> ```

7. You reference razor component in mvc view such as;

> ```
> <component type="typeof(MyHomeComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
> ```

You also use blazor routing to access blazor component pages.

Comment: I have updated your post because most of the code was not rendered correctly by StackOverflow, and xml/html tags are not visible if they are not in proper code tag. I believe there are missing lines after "</NotFound>" but they were also missing before my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution in Fiodar Sazanavets - SignalR on .NET 6 - the Complete Guide_ The easiest way to enable real-time two-way HTTP communication on .NET 6 book. its a grate one.
the solution is in page 41. Because of copyright reasons i won't copy the solution here.