# Blazor-WASM Loading screen in MVC Application

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So i have an mvc app thats including blazor components by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997246/how-to-enable-use-configure-webassembly-blazor-in-existing-net-mvc-project) tutorial.

Now i want the app to show an loading screen or an loading "text" (like Loading...) in the corner while blazor is beeing initialized, as the default blazor wasm app does.

Does anyone have tried this or thinks of an solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try creating a default Blazor WASM app, seeing how it does it, then replicating that in your own app?

Comment: the default app is included in mvc (there 2 projects) and it does it by changing the "Loading..." to the actual content but this wont work for me because my app is driven by mvc and not wasm, it's just using it

Comment: What's stopping you from doing the same thing? Use some JavaScript to conditionally hide and show different elements?

Comment: Yeah i could do that but... thats why i ask how can i do that. Thank you but i don't know how. For me it's just blazor initalising i don't know the behind work, if you know it could you please help?    Edit: i think i could like "deliver" the page without the blazorr elements and a placeholder and then when blazor is initialized correct this but how exactly would this work

Comment: It'd work exactly like you described it. Page loads, have some default content displayed. Once the Blazor component has loaded whatever it needs, then run some code to change what's displayed to show the Blazor component instead of the default content. It's really that easy. You've got to learn to break your work down into tasks, then try to implement those tasks. If you get stuck, then create a [mcve] and clearly explain which part you're stuck on.

Comment: I got an idea that might work, the default app is rendering to #app. You could change that to a class (for example "blazor") and Render it, then this component could do the rest

Comment: it worked! i created a "Load.razor" that's invoked without any stuff that could be used as a loading bar. On it's OnAfterRenderAsync i called a little ts script thats removing the class thats making blazor objects invisible from all blazor objects

Comment: Very good. See, you didn't really need us after all! Just a little bit of thought and planning, and the willingness to try something out.