# In Blazor, how to build the @onclick markup completely in code AND have it execute

Tags: blazor

In a Blazor with .NET 7, this markup will fire the HelloClick event in my @code block:

```cs
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span @onclick="(() => HelloClick(42))" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;">HELLO</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a need to create span tags completely in code. The generated span tags are all loaded into a variable called itemsToClick and are displayed thusly:

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>@((MarkupString)itemsToClick)</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is the code that produces the span elements:

```cs
private string itemsToClick = string.Empty;
...

//In a function
{
  ...
  itemsToClick = string.Empty;
  List<string> spans = new List<string>();
  foreach (int spanId in spanIds)
  {
    string onClick = string.Format($@"@onclick=""(() => HelloClick({spanId}))""");
    string span = string.Format(@$" <span {onClick} style=""display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;"">Hello</span>");
    spans.Add(span);
  }
  if (spans.Count > 0)
    itemsToClick = string.Join(", ", spans.ToArray());
  ...
}
```

However, the functions are **not** called when the span markup is clicked. I get no error when I view things in the browser debug (F12) window. The span element is there, properly sized and displayed, only the event does not work.

I have verified that the code output is exactly the same as the markup, except for different ids for the function parameter. However, using F12 to inspect the code does show differences. For the first (working) method, I do *not* see the onclick verbiage at all:
[image]

For the second method that does not work, I *do* see the onclick verbiage:
[image]

For the code generation method, it seems as though the onclick code is treated as markup and not as an event. Is there a way to correct that with my approach? I have looked at Templates and Render Fragment, but they do not seem to be able to do what I need to do. Or is there a way to do this with Template / Render fragment?
I should also add that I am not looking for a JS solution.

Comment: This has been asked before; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196812 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368714

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor onclick event not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196812/blazor-onclick-event-not-triggered)

Comment: Mx and Jim, the links you provided were informative, but the solutions did not apply. I had all of the headers called out, the location of the js file already was in the preferred location, and the necessary usings/includes were present in my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach blazor events like `@onclick` to a `MarkupString`, it only renders raw HTML content.
What you need to use is `RenderFragment` and `RenderTreeBuilder` [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#manually-build-a-render-tree-rendertreebuilder).

Here's a [snippet example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QucdaXkzBsMSUyLK)

```cs
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span @onclick="(() => HelloClick(42))" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;">HELLO</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in itemsToClick)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>

@code {
    List<int> spanIds = new(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    List<RenderFragment> itemsToClick = new();
    void HelloClick(int val)
    {
        var newFragment = new RenderFragment(builder =>
        {
        builder.AddContent(0,@<td>
            @foreach (int spanId in spanIds)
            {
            <span @onclick="() => HelloClick(spanId)" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;">Hello</span>
            }
        </td>);
        });
        itemsToClick.Add(newFragment);
    }
}
```

Or, you can manually build the render tree instead of using the razor syntax as in the first example.

```cs
void HelloClick(int val)
{
    var newFragment = new RenderFragment(builder =>
    {
        foreach (int spanId in spanIds)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "span");
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "style", "display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;");
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, () => HelloClick(spanId)));
            builder.AddContent(3, "Hello");
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    });
    itemsToClick.Add(newFragment);
}
```

#### Additional Guidance

Edit: As @MrC mentioned in the comments. Sequence numbers should be hardcoded and not dynamically generated. [MS Doc reasons why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-problem-with-generating-sequence-numbers-programmatically)

Comment: edit just added `csharp` to the markup code blocks to show the colouring!

Comment: RBee -  FYI -  see this MS article on why you shouldn't use dynamic sequencing in RenderTreeBuilder blocks - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-problem-with-generating-sequence-numbers-programmatically

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks! I was not aware of this.

Comment: NP - I once did it too.  There's more detail here - https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3 - and here - https://www.infoq.com/articles/blazor-rendertree-explained/

Comment: Excellent, this should work and I have a much better understanding of RenderFragment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@RBee's answer applies.

Here's another take on coding the answer which defines a `RenderFragment<T>` and then calls it in the for loop.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-3 p-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Add">Add another Span</button>
</div>

@foreach (var id in _spanIds)
{
    <div class="m-1">
        @Frag(id)
    </div>
}

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Selected Span: @_selected</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private int _selected;
    private int _count = 4;
    private List<int> _spanIds = new() { 1, 2, 3 };

    private void HelloClick(int value)
    {
        _selected = value;
    }

    private void Add()
    {
        _spanIds.Add(_count);
        _count++;
    }

    private RenderFragment<int> Frag => value => __builder =>
    {
        <span @onclick="() => HelloClick(value)" style="display:inline-block; background-color: #04AB6D; border: none; color: white;">HELLO</span>
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks MrC, this will also meet my needs. Wish I could mark both answers as solutions. :)

Comment: @BarnumBailey - No, RBee's was the first correct answer and should be voted as such.  I just provided a different implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's possible to do it the way you're trying, but what you could do is use Javascript to add an onclick event to the span elements, which then calls your `HelloClick` method via JS interop.

I haven't tested this code so it may not be completely correct, but something like this should do the trick:

```cs
@code {
    [JSInvokable]
    public static void HelloClick(int number)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then call it from the javascript like this:

```js
DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('YourApp', 'HelloClick', 7);
```

You can read more about calling .NET code from Javascript in Blazor here, this is where I adapted the snippets from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks for your solution PS, but I do not want to go the JS route at this time. I have edited my post to say that now.

Comment: @BarnumBailey That's understandable, sorry that I couldn't be more helpful.