# I'm unable to create an @onclick event in Blazor, following an ASP.NET tutorial

Tags: asp.net, onclick, blazor

I'm following the ASP.NET tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R23v4lgHYQI&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oW8nviYduHq7bmKode-p8Wy&index=11), and I'm having trouble creating an onclick event. I'm using Blazor and the following code is a Razor file. I'm using .NET 8.0 preview.

[Image where code is more readable here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K2rY.png)

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using webtest.WebSite.Models
@using webtest.WebSite.Services
@inject JsonFileProductService ProductService

@namespace webtest.WebSite.Components

<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var jobAd in ProductService.GetJobAds())
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="@jobAd.Url" target="_blank">finn.no link</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@jobAd.Title</h5>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">
                @code{
                    //@onclick is a Blazor event
                }
                <button @onclick="@(e=>SelectAd(jobAd.Id))"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobAdModal" class="btn btn-primary">More info</button>
            </small>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code{
    JobAd selectedAd;
    string selectedAdId;

    void SelectAd(string adId){
        selectedAdId=adId;
        selectedAd=ProductService.GetJobAds().First(x => x.Id == adId);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello there");
    }
}
```

In line 25 and 26, I'm creating a button. The button is created successfully, but the function SelectAd() is never called. It's as if the @onclick command is not recognized and it doesn't know what to do with the following string.

However, even though there are code marked in red, the website and all the buttons compile just fine. What's going on here?

I tried simplifying by replacing the lambda expression with a function, but no luck.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxRUR.png)

```html
<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var jobAd in ProductService.GetJobAds())
    {
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <a href="@jobAd.Url" target="_blank">finn.no link</a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@jobAd.Title</h5>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">
                <button class="btn btn-primary"     @onclick="UpdateHeading">@currentButton</button>
            </small>
        </div>
    }
</div>




@code{
    JobAd selectedAd;
    string selectedAdId;
    string currentButton = "Initial button";
    string newButton = "Update button!!";
    void SelectAd(string adId){
        selectedAdId=adId;
        selectedAd=ProductService.GetJobAds().First(x => x.Id == adId);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello there");
    }
    private void UpdateHeading(){
        currentButton=newButton;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code in code blocks and not as images.

Comment: Remove `@code { //@onclick is a blazor event }`. You should only have one `@code` block in your component.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Unfortunately no change though.

Comment: Try: `@onclick="() => SelectAd(jobAd.Id)"`

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: Which project template are you using?  This sounds like server side rendering with a static page.

Comment: It's an "ASP.NET Core web app" with Razor pages. Yes, it's server side rendering. I thinks it's a dynamic page, but I'm not too familiar with these terms. (I've been able to update a JSON-file by making a specific query.)

Comment: @HåvardBakke - see my answer.  Does this basic code run?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, worked in .net 7 blazor server, not in .net 8

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found a fix, following @rvnlord's answer [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196812/blazor-onclick-event-not-triggered). By adding an `_Imports.razor` file to the `Components` folder with the lines

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

the original code ran fine, without further changes. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Why is this answer getting dislikes? It's literally the solution to the problem.

Comment: It's line-for-line identical with the other answer - it contains no unique code at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm not trying to be original, I'm just trying to solve the problem. I have restated the same answer that I've linked to, for the convenience of anyone reading this question.

Comment: If that's the case, the question should be marked as a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using data-toggle which probably breaks the onclick handling. You can try removing that to see if your handler is called then.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked is using **[Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor)** components, i.e., `.cshtml`, and you're using **[Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor)** components, i.e., `.razor`  (all very confusing).

So, most likely your project is not configured to use Blazor components. I would suggest creating a new *Blazor Web App* project which is also using the same frameworks as *ASP.NET Core web App*. However, this project template is already configured to work with Blazor *.razor* components.

[image]

Make sure to select either of the *Interactive* options below.

[image]

Also, you need to include a page render mode at the top of your *.razor* component for interactivity.

```
@attribute [RenderModeServer]
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
```

Then your code should work as is.

Comment: Thank you! Fortunately managed to fix it without making a new project. Only took me six hours (:

Comment: NP! A **Tip** though: if you're trying to learn at the moment, I would recommend learning using .NET 7 or 6 not 8,  8 is still in preview mode and frequent changes will be made and learning resources are scarce.  And If you're learning Blazor then learn using Blazor server or Blazor webassembly.

Answer (score -1):

This is just syntax. You don't need the second `@` in the event and the event object `e` is in the wrong spot, but you don't need it anyway.

This should be your syntax;

`@onclick="() => SelectAd(jobAd)"`

If you did want to make use of the event object, you could adjust `SelectAd` and pass it in like so;

`@onclick="(e) => SelectAd(jobAd,e)"`

```
private void SelectAd(string adId, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```